# How to put a max return percentage on an IF function?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have this formula:

=IF(C7="","",IF(C6>C5,IF(C7<=C5,0,(C7-C5)/(C6-C5)),IF(C6<C5,IF(C7>=C5,0,ABS(C7-C5)/(C5-C6)))))

referencing these cells:

[image]

But I need to cap that 200% at 120%; where would I put my MAX at?

Comment: You actually need to use `MIN`. Probably just over the entire inner IF

Comment: Ah, I was putting it in the wrong place.  It kept wanting me to multiple by 1.2 for some reason.  Here's what worked:  =IF(C7="","",MIN(IF(C6>C5,IF(C7<=C5,0,(C7-C5)/(C6-C5)),IF(C6<C5,IF(C7>=C5,0,ABS(C7-C5)/(C5-C6)))),1.2))